# Why foreach over this.Controls collection does not work correctly when child.Parent property changed inside the loop

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, foreach

Well, I have this code, it works properly if I use for loop over foreach loop. I try to change background and foreground colors for all Labels on form using foreach to process every control. In foreach I've made a condition that determines if control in current iteration is Label and if that's true it will change color.

The problem is foreach runs over every Control on form but if I add condition and any action in it, this foreach will count 22 Labels on form but I have 44 labels over the picturebox.

If I add for loop or while loop, it will start foreach many times and all Labels will be painted. Is that right way to paint all Labels using loops? See the code below:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Changes background color of each label on form 
        /// to transparent and foreground color to white.
        /// </summary>
        public void PaintLabels()
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {              
                    c.Parent = Map;
                    c.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    c.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is if I don't add `for` loop around that `foreach`, this code will work only with 22 Labels on form though condition doesn't say about that. So I need to use `for` loop with counter from 0 to 6 to force this code to work correctly, but I think that's bad practice and want to find correct solution for this task. Why that `foreach` does not pick all child items on a single iteration?

---

Standalone MRE for LinqPad (or just console app)

```
var control = new Form();
var group = new GroupBox();
control.Controls.Add(group);
var Map = new GroupBox();
control.Controls.Add(Map);
foreach (var element in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
{
    group.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = element.ToString() });
}

foreach (Control c in group.Controls)
{
        c.Parent = Map;
        Console.WriteLine(c.Text); // 0 2 4 8 instead of 0 1 2 ... 9
}
```

Comment: This is from here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-make-a-transparent-label-over-a-picturebox1 Because I have picturebox on form

Comment: `foreach` works fine, and your `for` loop makes no sense. Why would you think you need to run the `foreach` 6 times for it to work? It either works the first time, or it doesn't work at all - you don't use `i` inside the `for` loop at all, so you're just (ridiculously) running the **same exact code** multiple times for absolutely no reason.

Comment: If I don't use for loop, this code will paint only 22 Labels but I need 44 Labels to be printed

Comment: And if I do loop from 0 to 2 for example, it will paint 30 Labels

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: OP's code makes no sense, and there's no clear indication of what they are trying to do. I agree with `c.Parent = Map` in the loop looking suspicious. OP should [edit] the post and explain what exactly they are trying to do, because this sounds very much like an XY problem at this point.

Comment: Ok I will explain what I wanna do

Comment: @KenWhite I edited it and explained what I mean

Comment: You still have not provided a [mre] as has been requested.

Comment: @KenWhite well how about that?

Comment: Still not a [mre]. Did you actually read the linked post?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `c.Parent = Map;`? And, do you have all the **44 labels** in the same container?

Comment: Of course I did and I tested my code and tried other things. Also I looked for it on the Internet. I removed extra parts of code

Comment: @dr.null because I want to paint Labels, these Labels are over the picturebox on form. I found this page to do it: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-make-a-transparent-label-over-a-picturebox1 and also never mind how many labels I have, I could generate it in code or just create in Designer

Comment: Loop to set the `Parent` and `BackColor` properties just once in the constructor if these properties don't change. `foreach (Control c in this.Controls.OfType<Label>()) { ... }`. In the `PaintLabels` method, loop to set the labels `ForeColor` property. Also, you might need to [adjust the locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943982/14171304) of the labels due to changing their parent.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov many thanks

Comment: Missing part in my last comment: _In the PaintLabels method, loop the **Map.Controls** collection to set the labels ForeColor property._ Just like your other question.

Comment: @dr.null yep thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to everyone who posted answer and comments. Now I get it and wrote code to solve my problem. I needed to find all controls on form and store it in [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) I used `foreach` iteration for that. After that I changed parent of every element in the list using `for` loop and then called next method to paint all these labels. See the code of solution:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Changes parent of Labels on form. Stores all Labels in list 
        /// and then changes parent of each Label that is stored in list
        /// </summary>
        public void ChangeParent()
        {
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    list.Add(c);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
            {
                list[i].Parent = this.Map;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Changes background color of each label on Map picturebox to transparent and foreground color to white.
        /// For first and last labels it defines different colors
        /// </summary>
        public void PaintLabels()
        {  
            //Loop iterates every control whose parent is Map on this form
            foreach (Control c in this.Map.Controls) 
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {    
                    c.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    c.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    if (c.Text == "1")
                    {
                        c.ForeColor = Color.Aqua;
                    }
                    if (c.Text == "44")
                    {
                        c.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```